# Pick up a color from canvas

Tags: processing

I want to pick up a color from drawn canvas.
I found `get()` function, but it can get color only from image.
Is there some way to get color from current canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [get()](https://processing.org/reference/get_.html) colour from your current canvas: just address the PGraphics instance you need (even the global one) and be sure to call [loadPixels()](https://processing.org/reference/get_.html) first.

Here's tweaked version of **Processing > Examples > Basics > Image > LoadDisplayImage**:

```
/**
 * Load and Display 
 * 
 * Images can be loaded and displayed to the screen at their actual size
 * or any other size. 
 */

PImage img;  // Declare variable "a" of type PImage

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  // The image file must be in the data folder of the current sketch 
  // to load successfully
  img = loadImage("https://processing.org/examples/moonwalk.jpg");  // Load the image into the program  
}

void draw() {
  // Displays the image at its actual size at point (0,0)
  image(img, 0, 0);
  // Displays the image at point (0, height/2) at half of its size
  image(img, 0, height/2, img.width/2, img.height/2);

  //load pixels so they can be read via get()
  loadPixels();
  // colour pick
  int pickedColor = get(mouseX,mouseY);

  // display for demo purposes
  fill(pickedColor);
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,30,30);
  fill(brightness(pickedColor) > 127 ? color(0) : color(255));
  text(hex(pickedColor),mouseX+21,mouseY+6);
}
```

It boils down to calling `loadPixels();` before `get()`.
Above we're reading pixels from the sketch's global PGraphics buffer.
You can apply the same logic but reference a different PGraphics buffer depending on your setup.

Comment: `loadPixels();` works as I expected!

Thank you for your perfect answer!